# Creating a dynamic xml document

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dynamic

Hi you is it possible to create a dynamica xml with xdocument I've been trying but it appears that it returns an exception about having a wrong structure

My code is the following

```
public string ReadTest(Stream csvFile)
        {
            XDocument responseXml = new XDocument( new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));   

            try
            {
                if ( csvFile != null || csvFile.Length!=0)
                {
                    responseXml.Add(new XElement("root"));

                    //using(CsvFileReader reader=new CsvFileReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\toshibapc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WCFLecturaCSV\WCFLecturaCSV\App_Data\archivo.csv"))){
                    using (CsvFileReader reader = new CsvFileReader(csvFile))
                    {

                        CsvRow row = new CsvRow();
                        List<String> headers = new List<string>();


                        while (reader.ReadRow(row))
                        {
                            int cont = 0;

                            XElement dato = new XElement("AccountInfos", new XElement("Info"));
                            XElement datos=null;
                            foreach (String s in row)
                            {
                                if(s.Equals("AccountIDToMove", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)|| s.Contains("AccountNameToMove") || s.Contains("NewParentAccountID") || s.Contains("NewParentAccountName")){
                                    headers.Add(s);                                    
                                }
                                else{
                                    if (s != String.Empty)
                                    {
                                        datos = new XElement(headers[cont], s); //.Append("<" + headers[cont] + ">" + s + "<" + headers[cont] + "/>");
                                        dato.Add(datos);
                                    }                                    
                                   }
                                cont++;                                
                            }
                            if (headers.Count == 4 && datos != null)
                                responseXml.Add(dato);

                        } // fin de while 
                    }

                } // Check if no file i sent or not info on file

            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                //oError = ex.Message;
            }
            return responseXml.ToString();
        }
```

What i would like to acomplish by using this code is to get an xml like this

```
<xml version="1.0">
<root>
<AccountInfos>
<Info>
<AccountIDToMove>312456</AccountIDToMove>
<AccountNameToMove>Burger Count</AccountNameToMove>
<NewParentAccountID>453124</NewParentAccountID>
<NewParentAccountName> Testcom sales 1</NewParentAccountName>
</Info>
<Info>
<AccountIDToMove>874145</AccountIDToMove>
<AccountNameToMove>Mac Count</AccountNameToMove>
<NewParentAccountID>984145</NewParentAccountID>
<NewParentAccountName> Testcom sales 1</NewParentAccountName>
</Info>
</AccountInfos>
</root>
```

For any answer or help thank you so much

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "dynamic xml"?

Comment: is like any normal csv file separated by commas by dynamic I mean create it basically depending on what I read from the csv file

Comment: This is the exception "This operation would create an incorrectly structured document" which is caused because for sure i am creating a wrong structure using the code above as you stated dbc creating more than one root element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding multiple roots to your document.  You initially add one here:

```
                responseXml.Add(new XElement("root"));
```

And later add more root elements in a loop here:

```
                            responseXml.Add(dato);
```

However, [each XML document must have exactly one single root element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element).  Thus you probably want to do:

```
                            responseXml.Root.Add(dato);
```